# DNS: Can I list 1 host in 2 separate domains?

Tags: dns

I want to test something, but I lack sufficient number of machines so I was going to overlay a subnetwork listing the same hosts under different names. I can't think of any problem with this, but I want to double check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list a host (IP address) under as many domains (names) as you wish.  DNS `A` records work as a directory listing indicating what IP address(es) to use to connect to the named host.

Web servers use virtual hosts to allow different names to resolve to different content.  Some web hosting plans work this way with multiple domains being served by the same web server.

Comment: something tells me this may only be possible if the two networks don't eventually share a parent domain, as in, not on any LAN.